# Issue Deploying R Shiny App to shinyapps.io

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, rsconnect

I'm having an issue deploying an updated version of my Shiny App.  Whenever I attempt to deploy, my system stalls on `Starting Upload Now` and I get this error repeatedly.

This output is with the `Show Diagnostic Information when Publishing` flag turned on.

```
----- Deployment error -----
Error in force(code) : Could not upload file.
Calls: <Anonymous> -> withStatus -> force
 
----- Error stack trace -----
Error in force(code) : Could not upload file.
Calls: <Anonymous> -> withStatus -> force
Error during wrapup: length(max.lines) <= 1 is not TRUE
Error: no more error handlers available (recursive errors?); invoking 'abort' restart
Execution halted
```

Does anyone have thoughts on what might be going wrong?

Deployment Command

```
rsconnect::deployApp(appDir = "~/BP/APP/APP/R", appFileManifest = "C:/Users/maxwe/AppData/Local/Temp/9851-d65e-68db-ef2e",      account = "ACOUNT_NAME", server = "shinyapps.io", appName = "APP_NAME_FY2021",      appTitle = "APP_NAME_FY2021", launch.browser = function(url) {         message("Deployment completed: ", url)     }, lint = FALSE, metadata = list(asMultiple = FALSE, asStatic = FALSE),      logLevel = "verbose")
```

Comment: Not sure. Firewall? Windows app permission? Typo in the host/port? Are you using UI or code to push your app?

Comment: I'm using the UI.  I have not made any changes to my Firewall settings or any windows application permissions and I have deployed this app and other apps dozens of times.

Comment: @r2evans I've added the deployment command to my post